# RoR query condition: does not contain any of a list of attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, object

I feel like there should be a simple answer for this question, but I haven't been able to manage.

I have 3 models: User, Course, and Textbook.  My model associations are working just fine, but I will include them if necessary.  In my application, I want a view to display the courses for which the user owns textbooks and all other courses for which the user does NOT own the textbooks.  In pseudocode, it should look like

```
@courses_with_books = current_user.textbooks
@courses_without_books = current_user.courses.where(:id != @courses_with_books.course_ids)
```

I can complete that second line using complicated loops, but the processes seemed silly so I've been researching a way to gather the information I need with a single query and have yet come up with nothing.  Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 1):

In general, if you want to check that some attribute is not inside of some given collection, try 'NOT IN':

```
current_user.courses.where("id NOT IN ?", @courses_with_books.course_ids)
```

For more on Active Record Queries, check out [the Active Record Query Interface Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html).

Comment: So making use of both your suggestions, I did the following:
array = curent_user.textbooks.collect(&:course_id)
courses_without_books = current_user.courses.where('id not in?', array)
This runs without error, but when i display <%= courses_without_books %> in the view, #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x2136d0f0> is all that comes up.  I need to display the course titles by doing something like <%= @courses_without_books.title %> but this results in an error:
SQLite3::SQLException: ambiguous column name: id

Comment: I'm not quite sure on this one, but sometimes, when dealing with more than just one table, ambiguity problems can arise because it's not clear which `id` one is referring to, since both tables have an attribute named `id`. Because of that, it's never a bad idea to explicitly add the table name in a query. So you're new statement might have to look like that: `current_user.courses.where("courses.id NOT IN ?", @courses_with_books.course_ids)`. Also take a look at varatis' answer.

Comment: The reason why the error might be happening that late is because of a think called lazy loading (google it for more detailed info). ActiveRecord doesn't actually execute the query on the relation until you're "doing" something with it, like iterating through it and displaying it in the view. This is not true for all kind of queries, though.

Answer (score 0):

rathrio is on the right path. I think for the first part you could do

`@courses_with_books = current_user.textbooks.collect(&:course)`

If you're trying to display their `title`s, do

```
<% @courses_with_books.each do |cwb| %>
  <%= cwb.title %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: So making use of both your suggestions, I did the following:
array = curent_user.textbooks.collect(&:course_id)
courses_without_books = current_user.courses.where('id not in?', array)
This runs without error, but when i display <%= courses_without_books %> in the view, #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x2136d0f0> is all that comes up.  I need to display the course titles by doing something like <%= @courses_without_books.title %> but this results in an error:
SQLite3::SQLException: ambiguous column name: id

Comment: See updated answer. Does this solve your problem? Note that @courses_without_books is an array of courses. It doesn't have any "title" attribute.